# Scroll Drop-down li element until element is visibile

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

hi i have an AngularJs directive which select an item depending on the "key-pressed" event. This works fine.

The problem comes when there is a scroll-bar , the elements are hidden and i can't see them.

here is the working code: http://plnkr.co/edit/9WhAuxOyK4l6yDeRmvle?p=preview

this is the Angular directive

```
myApp.directive('keypressEvents', 
function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {
        console.log('linked');
        element.parent().parent().bind('keypress', function (e) {
        var letter = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
        var target = e.target; 
        var charat = element[0].textContent.charAt(13);  
        if(charat === letter){ 
              element.addClass("active");
              element.scrollTop = 100;  ///<---- the following statement dose not works and how do i calculate this value in javascript? 
        }
        else{
              element.removeClass("active");
        }
        });
    }
};
});
```

how do i calculate the offest in javascript and which is the best function to use to move in the right position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the scroll top function must be applied to ul elements and must move of the offset taken from the li element

```
              element.parent()[0].scrollTop = element[0].offsetTop;
```